# Syntax error near "else" in Verilog, in an initial block, next to assert

Tags: verilog, alu, testbench

I'm trying to make a self-checking testbench for an ALU I'm designing for an extra credit assignment. Here's what I have:

```
module testbench();
    wire [31:0] a, b, y;
    wire [2:0] f;
    wire zero;

    alu test(a, b, f, y, zero);

    initial begin
        a = 0; b = 0; f = 3'd2; #100;
        assert (y === 0) else $warning("0 + 0 failed");
        a = 0; b = 8'hFFFFFFFF; f = 3'd2; #100;
        assert (y === 8'hFFFFFFFF) else $warning("0 + FFFFFFFF failed");
        a = 1; b = 8'hFFFFFFFF; f = 3'd2; #100;
        assert (y === 0) else $warning("1 + FFFFFFFF failed");
        a = 8'h000000FF; b = 1; f = 3'd2; #100;
        assert (y === 8'h00000100) else $warning("FF + 1 failed");
    end
endmodule
```

I'm getting four critical warnings, all of them saying 'Syntax error near "else".', for each of the lines with the assert statements. I don't know why that's happening, I have the statements in the initial block. Does anyone know if I'm missing something here?

Comment: Are you using Verilog or SystemVerilog? There's a big difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `logic` instead of `wire`. You cannot make procedural assignment s to `wire` signals.

You need to use `32'h` instead of `8'h`

Your file should have a `.sv` file extension; otherwise might be compiled with Verilog syntax rules.